# Tabulação com jquery

Tags: html

Como que eu faço para tabular uma frase e colocá-la uma debaixo da outra ?
Deixa eu explicar:
Estou usando este código para adicionar dentro de uma div:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#cbo_vitrine').change(function(){ 

  itemsel = $("#cbo_vitrine option:selected").text();

           if(itemsel == "REF-01")

                $("#det_prod_vitrine").append("FLOR BATIDO - MARROM - Nº: 23 ao 41 - R$34,99");

           if(itemsel == "REF-02")

                $("#det_prod_vitrine").append("MEDALHÃO - MARROM - Nº: 33 ao 44 - R$34,99");

           //if(itemsel == "REF-...")       
   });  
});
</script>
```

Eu seleciono em uma select e vai adicionando com append. Só que está ficando meio embolado.
Detalhe: Não estou trazendo nada de banco de dados e sim está estático.
Alguém me sugere algo mais prático ou me orienta a tabular ???
Grato professores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode incluir a frase numa `div`, por exemplo, porque a `div` ocupa toda a largura da linha fazendo com que cada frase fique numa linha única:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#cbo_vitrine').change(function(){ 

  itemsel = $("#cbo_vitrine option:selected").text();

           if(itemsel == "REF-01")

                $("#det_prod_vitrine").append("<div>FLOR BATIDO - MARROM - Nº: 23 ao 41 - R$34,99</div>");

           if(itemsel == "REF-02")

                $("#det_prod_vitrine").append("<div>MEDALHÃO - MARROM - Nº: 33 ao 44 - R$34,99</div>");

           //if(itemsel == "REF-...")       
   });  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="cbo_vitrine">
   <option>REF-01</option>
   <option>REF-02</option>
</select>
<div id="det_prod_vitrine"></div>
```

Ou quebrar a linha com um `<br>` no final da frase:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#cbo_vitrine').change(function(){ 

  itemsel = $("#cbo_vitrine option:selected").text();

           if(itemsel == "REF-01")

                $("#det_prod_vitrine").append("FLOR BATIDO - MARROM - Nº: 23 ao 41 - R$34,99<br>");

           if(itemsel == "REF-02")

                $("#det_prod_vitrine").append("MEDALHÃO - MARROM - Nº: 33 ao 44 - R$34,99<br>");

           //if(itemsel == "REF-...")       
   });  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="cbo_vitrine">
   <option>REF-01</option>
   <option>REF-02</option>
</select>
<div id="det_prod_vitrine"></div>
```